# How manually handle deeplink in compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-deep-link

[In this section](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#handle) says what if use *launchMode* **not** *standard* Navigation will **not** automatically navigate to deeplink, however when i send intent with deeplink, Navigation navigates automatically, but i dont want it, i want control incoming intents and decide (ex: pin-code screen don't heed to be skipped)

It happens when i describe composable's deeplink parameter

```
navGraphBuilder.composable(
        route = "route",
        deepLinks = listOf(
            navDeepLink { 
                uriPattern = "deeplink"
            }
        )
    ) {}
```